# Wordpress на сайте ничего не происходит при изменение php файлов

Tags: wordpress, polylang

В общем, хотел сделать перевод у себя на сайте. Нашёл нужный файл, стал использовать функции pll__, pll_e и т.п. Смотрю, изменений ноль. Не понимал почему. Долго пытался что-то искать, смотреть, ничего не изменяется. Я пробовал добавлять/убирать целые функции, итог - ноль.

Попробовал я убрать целую кнопку, обновляю страничку - ничего не убралось. Захожу с другого браузера (браузер тот-же, но пользователь в браузере другой) - кнопка пропала, всё ок. Ставлю её назад, теперь и тут изменений ноль. То-есть он как-бы один раз скачал сайт, а потом не изменяет.

ctrl + f5 я пробовал.
f12 - очистка кэша и жёсткая перезагрузка тоже.

Я ещё пробовал менять язык на сайте (плагин polylang, значки на сайте), не помогало. А вот только что попробовал, сайт начало грузить быстро и смена языка стало помогать. Остальное, так и не работает. С чем может быть такое связанно? Мне нужно что-бы всё нормально изменялось.

Comment: Похоже на говнохостинг.

Comment: Плагины кеширования в топку!.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит заглянуть в раздел плагины и поискать там кеширующий плагин. Потом либо временно отключить его на время разработки либо нажимать в нем очистить кеш после каждого изменения.

Comment: Не получается найти, где это?

Comment: В админке вордпресс есть раздел плагины. Там нужно внимательно посомтреть все установленные плагины все названия проверить нет ли среди них кеширующих плагинов.